# Django reset password get Server Error 500 when deployed to production in Azure

Tags: python, django, azure

I'm trying to implement a reset password feature in my Django app using django.contrib.auth` like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
    path('admin_main', views.admin_main, name='admin_main'),
    path('admin_csv', views.admin_csv, name='admin_csv'),
    path('admin_pdf', views.admin_pdf, name='admin_pdf'),

    path('reset_password/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name="reset_password"),
    path('reset_password_sent/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name="password_reset_done"),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name="password_reset_confirm"),
    path('reset_password_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name="password_reset_complete"),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Everything works just fine during development but in production (Azure App Service) when I introduce the email to reset the password and submit the form, I get "Server Error (500)" and the reset password mail is not send, any idea why could this be?

Also, the rest of the web modules are working correctly in production, DEBUG mode is off and ALLOWED_HOST is set.

The SMTP configuration is as follows:

```
#SMTP Configuration
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '******@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
```

Comment: You really need to get logs from the deployed app. `Server Error (500)` is not really useful.

Comment: Can't be sure without logs, but the most likely issue is that your email settings are not correctly configured for production, so an exception is raised when Django tries to send mail.

Comment: I'm looking at the log stream within Azure Portal but it doesn't give too much additional information "POST /reset_password/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145, is there anyway I can see additional error information?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `reset_password/` the only endpoint that returns 500? Perhaps you have to set `ALLOW_HOSTS`?

Comment: Yes, is the only endpoint that is returning 500, the other views are working, I can login and use the other module's app, also DEBUG is off and the ALLOW_HOST is set

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution I went on this link https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and clicked on Continue. After that it started working.